# Formatting Tables in Htmltables for R

Tags: html, r, html-table, css-tables

How can you easily change the column width in an htmltable in R.  I am using the htmltable package.

Any help would be appreciated

```
htmlTable(DataFrame, align = "c",
      rnames = FALSE,
      caption = "<b> <center> <font face = Times New Roman> Table 1.  Population By Territory  <br> <br>",
      tfoot = "<b> Source </b> <br> [1]  Random Data Source",
      header = paste(c(" Territory", "Number of People")),
      css.caption = "color:red;",
      col.rgroup = c("none", "#ADADAD"),
      padding.tspanner = "", ctable = TRUE,
      css.cell = "<td width = 110px>",
```

)

Comment: `help.search("htmlTable")` returns "no results found". And ... `install.packages("htmltable")` returns `  package ‘htmltable’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)`

Comment: `css.cell = "width: 110px"`, not `css.cell = "<td width = 110px>"`

Answer (score 1):

The bug in the code is primarily the `css.cell` argument, this is html code and not [cascade-style](https://html.com/css/) as expected. What you probably wanted to do was:

```
htmlTable(DataFrame, align = "c",
      rnames = FALSE,
      caption = "<b> <center> <font face = Times New Roman> Table 1.  Population By Territory  <br> <br>",
      tfoot = "<b> Source </b> <br> [1]  Random Data Source",
      header = paste(c(" Territory", "Number of People")),
      css.caption = "color:red;",
      col.rgroup = c("none", "#ADADAD"),
      padding.tspanner = "", ctable = TRUE,
      css.cell = "width: 110px", # <-- drop the "td" stuff, this all goes into the style="" for the element
)
```